# Put jumping image over buttons

Tags: android, image, button

I'm writing an application for android and I have difficulties with put some images over some buttons. In my layout I have three buttons on the middle of the screen below each others. I have a little image which is jumping on the screen randomly. My problem is that this little image is jumping over the buttons and not behind them. So this image should jumping behind these buttons. I copy my xml and my java code. :

```
ImageView img1;
Button btn1;

Timer timer;
TimerTask timerTask;
final Handler handler = new Handler();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_first_screen);

    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    this.setContentView(R.layout.activity_first_screen);

    android.support.v7.app.ActionBar actionbar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionbar.hide();

    startTimer();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {

    img1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.first);
    btn1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.start);

    btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,FirstScreen.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
    super.onResume();
}

//HEAD 1

public void startTimer(){

    timer = new Timer();

    initializeTimerTask();

    timer.schedule(timerTask, 1000, 1000);
}

public void initializeTimerTask() {

    timerTask = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    Random r = new Random();
                    int x = r.nextInt(250 - 80);
                    int y = r.nextInt(300 - 80);

                    img1.setX(x);
                    img1.setY(y);

                }
            });
        }
    };
}
```

And my xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="320dp"
android:layout_height="480dp"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="seth.hu.catchmeifyoucan.FirstScreen"
android:background="@drawable/hatter">


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/start"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:background="@drawable/buttonegy"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/start2"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:background="@drawable/buttonegy"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="130dp"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/start3"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:background="@drawable/buttonegy"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="220dp"/>


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/first"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:src="@drawable/pocs"/>
```

If anyone has an idea how to do this please response.

Comment: Did you tried putting the ImageView before the buttons in the layout?

Comment: Thanks. It solved my problem!